# Flash Player in Chrome isn't working

Tags: google-chrome, flash

I can't play Flash videos on YouTube in my Google Chrome. I have the latest version of Google Chrome (31.0.1650.57 m) and Adobe Flash Player plugin is activated, but instead of the video I see a black rectangle. I need help.

**edit**
When right clicked on on black square I see 2 options: `Movie not loaded` and `About Adobe Flash Player`

**RESOLVED**
The problem was in browser cache. After cleaning it out everything became to work as usual.

Comment: I asked the same question this morning. The solution was to disable the FVD video downloader extension. See here http://superuser.com/q/681009/42531. If aren't using that particular extension, post what you do have.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses pepper flash rather than adobe.

To set it follow the instructions here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/108086?hl=en

Comment: I've tried to use only one of them(only pepper or adobe) but the problem stayed the same: black square instead of video

Answer (score 0):

ive recently observed that if pandora is running at the same time i try to launch a flash instance in the browser, the tab hangs.  i just quit pandora and everything works...  maybe they both call the same DLLs or something weird like that.